# “She’s got a ticket to ride, but she don’t care” — why?

Tags: slang, verb-agreement, lyrics, do-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don't impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

In the famous Beatles song *[Ticket to ride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_to_Ride)*, it is said of the protagonist that ***“she don’t care”***. Why isn’t that *“she doesn’t care”*? Is it 1960s slang, Liverpool slang, something specific to music? I welcome any hint…

[image: “Ticket to ride” cover]