# What is the name of the difference between "doesn't" and "don't"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I came across a phrase like this today, which is obviously incorrect:

> The car don't run.

The correct version of this would be:

> The car doesn't run.

I wanted to explain the issue to someone, but I could not recall what property of the verb "do" is incorrect in the first sentence.

"Tense" is the first thing that comes to mind, but "do" and "does" are both in the present tense.

What is it about the word "do" that makes it incorrect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The grammaticality of "that don't impress me much"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar I don't think so; the asker in this case is looking for terminology.

Comment: Grammatical or not, [it don't](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+don+%27+t&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) seem to be a particularly new phenomenon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that they could be called *incorrect negative conjugations,* meaning that what makes "don't" incorrect is that it has been conjugated improperly.

Correct conjugation:

> The car doesn't run.

Incorrect conjugation:

> The car don't run.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I would just say that "do" has been conjugated incorrectly.

Comment: Yup: *conjugation* is what you do to verbs, and *declination* is what you do to nouns (except in English you don't do much if any declining). Both *conjugation* and *declination* are types of *inflection*.

Comment: @Martha: usually called "declension". "Declination" is something to do with geodesy.

Comment: @ColinFine: dammit, *that's* the word I was trying to think of. Thanks!

Comment: @ColinFine, actually some languages use the term "declination" in grammar. Also of note, the specific conjugation error here is the wrong grammatical person.

Comment: @Unreason: The OED gives that meaning as "Obsolete". Can you give a reference for the _current_ use of "declination" in that sense?

Comment: @ColinFine: No, not in English, I was just referring to rather irrelevant trivia that in some other languages (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/declension) it kept the form closer to the Latin root and that development to *declension* did not occur.

Comment: @Unreason: Ah, you meant _in_ some languages, not _about_ some languages, as I assumed. As you say, irrelevant on EL&U

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're looking for *number* ([grammatical number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number)), as in singular vs plural. The verb must [agree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29) in number with its subject.

In the third person ("the car"), the form *does* is singular, and *do* is plural. (So you'd say "The car doesn't run", using the singular *does* because *car* is singular, but "The cars don't run", using the plural *do* because *cars* is plural.)

```
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|              |         Singular         |          Plural          |
|              |                          |                          |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|Third person  | does                     | do                       |
|              |      The car doesn't run |      The cars don't run  |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|Second person | do                       | do                       |
|              |      You don't run       |      You (all) don't run |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|First person  | do                       | do                       |
|              |      I don't run         |      We don't run        |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

In modern English, with most verbs, it seems that the third person plural form is the same as the one used for both second and first person, in both singular and plural: only the third person singular is different.
(An exception is "be", which in the first person singular is "am".)

In many other languages, all forms are usually distinct. English also had e.g. the form like "dost" that was used for (first and) second person singular ("thou dost"), which is now lost.

Comment: Actually, though this is slightly related more correct would be the *grammatical person*.

Comment: @Unreason: Isn't *the car* third-person in both sentences? Does *person* include number too, these days?

Comment: the way I learnt it, it was always like that (hence the full names such as first person singular, third person nutral singular, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person#Grammatical_person_in_nominative_case_English_pronouns), furthermore grammatical person is specific to verb forms, where grammatical number deals with arrangement of nouns, pronouns, adjectives and verbs.

Comment: @Unreason: The way I learnt it, "person" just refers to first/second/third person… and person, number and tense(/aspect/mood) are three independent axes for a verb form; that's why the full names like "first person singular" specify both the person and the number. But under the way you learnt it, what is the name for *just* what I called "person", namely first/second/third?

Comment: Ok, I see your point; TEFL wiki talks about 3 persons in singular and 3 persons in plural (i.e. includes the number in the person, http://teflworldwiki.com/index.php/Grammatical_Person); while about.com does not (http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/personterm.htm). Overall it seems you are more correct; however I think you should have mentioned the person, as it is imprecise to say: '*does* is singular (true, but imprecise; more precise to say is that it agrees with *third person* singular), and *do* is plural (false; it agrees with all other persons; singular or plural)'.

Comment: @Unreason: I agree. To be precise, in the third person, *does* is singular and *do* is plural. Incidentally it so happens that the the first and second person forms are the same *do*, but that is an irrelevant coincidence. :-)

Comment: +1 I think yours answers the best this particular question.

Answer (score 3):

In Standard English, the present tense of the auxiliary verb *do* in the negative is *don’t* (contracted from *do not*) when the subject of the sentence is *I, you, we* or *they*. When the subject is *he, she* or *it*, it takes the form *doesn’t* (*does not*). In your example, *the car* could be replaced by *it*, so Standard English requires the sentence to be *The car doesn't run*.

(That’s the case with Standard English. The grammar of some other dialects is different and would allow *The car don’t run*.)

Comment: And in the 1880's British prestige dialects appear to have allowed it, judging from W S Gilbert

Comment: That might make an interesting piece of research.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is obvious if you undo the contraction: doesn't == does not, and don't == do not.

Then, you see that the difference is in conjugations of the verb "to do" in the present tense, which differs based on the subject (notably in use of the third-person singular):

> - I do
> - You do
> - He/She/It **does**
> - We do
> - They do

So when referring to one single thing that is not a participant in communication (a "third person"), you use "doesn't". In all other cases, use "don't".