# "My love don't cost a thing"

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don't impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

In the Jennifer Lopez [song](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/love-don%27t-cost-a-thing-lyrics-jennifer-lopez/def2bf135944d27e482569ec000d4cf5) "My Love Don't Cost a Thing" she says:

> My love don't cost a thing

Shouldn't it be like this?

> My love doesn't cost a thing

Why does she say so?