# It Don't Mean a Thing?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don't impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

There is a jazz piece called "It Don't Mean a Thing". Should that be "It Doesn't Mean a Thing?" I've also seen an album title called "The Sun Don't Lie".

Is this grammatically correct? If not, what kind of "effect" does it have?

Comment: Related: [The grammaticality of "that don't impress me much"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much/)

Comment: I'm not buying that as the duplicate. The linked question discusses "code switching" but doesn't actually address the grammaticality of "don't" for "doesn't". Perhaps there's a question about BSE that would make a better referral?

Comment: In this case it is grammatically correct african american dialect. This question has a useful answer that differs completely from the linked "duplicate".