# "She don't care about me": how to explain this?

Tags: grammaticality, dialects, verb-agreement, do-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don't impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

I know the rule, the correct form is: "she doesn't care about me," but I heard it in Lost series, I read it in many lyrics; is it a mistake by the speaker or the writer? Or is it informal?

I googled for it, but I didn't find useful results.