# "It doesn't matter" or "it don't matter "?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don’t impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

I am not a native English speaker, but until now what I read was to use **does** with **it**. But in a song *Don't Matter*, Akon uses ***It don't matter***  in a sentence. How's this grammatically correct?