# Is the sentence "My pain look like my pride" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I am a native Spanish speaker but I have been speaking English for more than ten years.

That sentence is part of the lyrics of a song. I get the feeling that it should be "My pain **looks** like my pride" but while I think that is correct it might be that there is another rule that I am not aware of.

So, is that sentence correct or not?

**edit:**

I am sorry i had not read the lyrics before this post, i had only listened to them hence why i missed an important aspect of it. 
the full sentence is a question and it looks like:

"Why do I feel like I deserve this? 
Why does my pain look like my pride?"
-linkin park, no roads left.

in which case there is the help verb to do and for that reason the second verb is not conjugated.

the whole question is irrelevant. sorry about that.

Comment: related "[That don't impress me much](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17973/16833)"

Comment: -1 Always cite the source, and quote with context. It is highly questionable if what you quote is a complete sentence from the source. Edit your post suitably, else it **may be closed**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you quoted the entire sentence from the lyric?

*Why does my pain look like my pride?* is a grammatically correct sentence as used in the song No Roads Left by Linkin Park.

Comment: it is in fact a quote from that song. i will update OP to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't agree. You can say "pains look like" (more than one pain) or "pain looks like" (one pain), but you cannot say "pains looks like" or "pain look like". It's just like you can say "The kid eats pie" or "The kids eat pie", but not "The kid eat pie" or "The kids eats pie".

Comment: what i had in mind but as a part of a song it couldn't be true that it is grammatically incorrect (at least i don't expect it from that artist).