# Is the expression "It don't" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, negation, verb-agreement, do-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The grammaticality of “that don’t impress me much”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

> It doesn't.

Usually, we say it this way, right? But I have seen some song lyrics using "it don't". 
(Examples are *Breakeven* by The Script and *Don't Matter* by Akon).

So is the expression "it don't" grammatically correct?