# "If it ain't in writing it don't exist" - why the broken grammar?

Tags: grammar, idioms

In the idiom "If it ain't ... it don't exist.", why is "don't" used instead of "doesn't"?

I'm thinking the intentional error might serve to draw the attention of the listener to the word "don't"/"doesn't", and thus make it more emphatic. I've noticed that when spoken, the word "don't" is stressed.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I presume that the _ain't_ and _don't_ are both intended to put the statement in a "folk wisdom" register.

Comment: "Ain't" on its own is not grammatically incorrect, though, just slang.

Comment: @satuon It's not slang, it's merely non-standard, as is 3dsg *don't*. They're both at home ('grammatically correct') in this register.

Comment: "It don't exist" is grammatically correct? Shouldn't the verb agree with the pronoun?

Comment: _It don’t_ is ungrammatical in **formal** English, but it's perfectly acceptable (and grammatical) in the folk dialect that proverbs like this are imitating.

Comment: This has been covered before, [many times over in fact](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/17973), the canonical question being [this one with quotes from cowboys, the Beatles, and yours truly, a Commander of the Excellent Order of the British Empire](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17973/). With regard to your last comment, I direct you to [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/52047/300) in particular. Saying that "don't" does not agree with "it" means that you still fail to understand that in a number of dialects/registers it in point of fact *does*.

Comment: You have to free yourself from thinking that *don't* is somehow intrinsically a plural verb. It is neither. It is just a word. Native speakers then take it and use it, and it's that usage alone that determines what it is. That's why we can say things like "the news is good", or "you are" when clearly referring to a single person, or take it up a notch and use "sheep" as both singular and plural, or take it up another notch and say "the dos and don'ts". In and of itself, *don't* don't mean a thing. It is a mere placeholder for whatever people collectively decide it can be a placeholder for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider also: [*politics ain't beanbag*](http://politicaldictionary.com/words/politics-aint-beanbag/), [*there ain't no such thing as a free lunch*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch), and probably many others that I can't think of at the moment. Adages that claim to offer no-nonsense straight-talk are often couched in folksy dialect, which presumably makes them sound more authentic. Non-standard English like *ain’t* or *it don’t* is acceptable and grammatical in such dialects.

Comment: "Ain't" on its own is not grammatically incorrect, just slang. I was asking about the "don't" part, specifically.

Comment: Probably because *doesn't* would sound inappropriately formal after *ain't*.

Comment: @satuon, _don’t_ is no more grammatically incorrect than _ain’t_ is. They are both forms that are perfectly fine in some registers of some variants of English, and not allowed in other registers and variants of English.

Comment: Btw, your answer does not really answer my question, because you focus on "ain't" exclusively, which is not broken grammar. The answer should deal with the "don't" part, instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How so? "It don't exists" is not grammatically correct, I think. It's either "It doesn't exist" or "They don't exist". The verb should agree with the pronoun, right?

Comment: @satuon, of course it is. There are many people who use it as their natural form in colloquial, informal registers. The exact same is true of _ain’t_. You wouldn’t use either in formal language, nor in writing (unless quoting speech or affecting an informal, colloquial register), and there are whole dialects and certainly idiolects where neither is ever used. I, for example, would never say _ain’t_ in any context (outside of fixed expressions), always _isn’t_. That makes it ungrammatical _in my idiolect_; not in English as a whole.

Comment: Even if "ain't" is an error, wouldn't it be a different type of error? Like how a spelling error is not a grammar error? Anyway, I don't see how using an informal variant of a word is a **grammar** error (as in that specific type of error).

Comment: The point is that _it don't_ is **not** an error in the same dialects where _ain't_ is not an error.

Comment: @phenry I edited your answer to make that point more explicit. Hope you agree with the change.

Comment: Spot on with the folksy angle.

Comment: @satuon, that is exactly what I am saying! _Ain’t_ is NOT a grammatical error in general; it is just an informal variant—and the exact same is true for _don’t_. In other words, the two are, as far as grammaticality is concerned, **completely parallel**. _Ain’t_ and _don’t_ are not grammatical errors in English as such, though one or both can be ungrammatical in _some_ dialects or idiolects.

Answer (score 4):

Much in line with my expectations, these are the figures I got from Google Books...

> *"**if it ain't broke** [don't fix it]"* [223,000 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22left%20the%20business%20more%20obscure%20than%22&sa=X&ei=adoHU8apDYLY0QW72YAg&ved=0CCAQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1800,cd_max:1/1/1997&tbm=bks#q=%22if%20it%20ain%27t%20broke%22&tbm=bks)
>    *"**if it ain't written** [down, it didn't happen]"* [183 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22left%20the%20business%20more%20obscure%20than%22&sa=X&ei=adoHU8apDYLY0QW72YAg&ved=0CCAQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1800,cd_max:1/1/1997&tbm=bks#q=%22if%20it%20ain%27t%20written%22&tbm=bks) (plus [45 more](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20it%20ain%27t%20written%22&biw=1128&bih=840&sa=X&ei=VN8HU8j_FIGW0AWkzYGwCQ&ved=0CCEQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1900,cd_max:12/31/1973&tbm=bks#q=%22if%20it%20ain%27t%20in%20writing%22&tbas=0&tbm=bks) for *ain't in writing*)

It's also worth mentioning that there seem to be more different ways of following the (highlighted) search term in those 183 results than in all the 223,000 above it. Also that the "broke" version goes back to at least the 1890s, whereas the "written" version seems to have first appeared in the 1970s.

Taking that into account, I would say the "reason" for the "ungrammaticality" in OP's version is mainly because *that's how the original was framed*. And since that original had already lasted for the best part of a century, the latter-day aphorist was simply taking the advice of his chosen model.

---

I will admit I don't recall ever hearing OP's specific follow-on *(it don't exist)*. Mostly I know the version I put above as a "general observation", and the unadorned *"If it ain't in writing, it just ain't"* when warning people about the (lack of) value in verbal agreements. But obviously the rationale for ungrammatically using *don't exist* in OP's case is even more that it's just an echo of the original.

Answer (score 0):

In Tom Brown's Schooldays, the word don't is used instead of doesn't. e.g.. 'it don't go there'  As these were public school boys I wonder if that was standard at the time instead of 'it doesn't go there.'

Comment: Nah. It was never "standard". Such usages in TBS simply indicate that the speaker isn't particularly well educated, and/or is speaking in a highly informal/relaxed context.