# Does "He do what he do." make grammatical sense?

Tags: grammar, slang, verb-agreement, colloquialisms, popularity

According to a [DMagazine.com headline](http://www.dmagazine.com/publications/d-magazine/2011/april/texas-rangers-manager-ron-washington-do-what-he-do?single=1), it reads:

> Ron Washington: He **do** what he **do**.

Is there any case we have to use **he do** or does it mean something different?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: It has to be "He does" if I'm not mistaken but here they use "He do"

Comment: It's a colloquialism. Don't imitate it. Ignore it for the time being. Once your grasp of the language has improved significantly, have another look at it: it'll make sense then.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [The grammaticality of “that don't impress me much”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17973/the-grammaticality-of-that-dont-impress-me-much)

Comment: Note that it makes perfect sense (to the extent that you can say that about anything in English).  It simply isn't grammatical, according to the "official rules".

Answer (score 1):

It is a variant of something that Ron Washington, the subject of the article said:

> ...“This team do what it does, **it do what it do**” and “I just think that’s the way my hair grow” and, of course, the slogan that launched a thousand t-shirts, “That’s the way baseball go.”

It is not considered grammatical in standard English. But it certainly makes sense. You just have to use the standard-grammatically correct form of the verb(s):

> He does what he does.

This is also a variant of the phrase

> It is what it is

in such sentences as

> Well, I don't like having to pay a $200 deposit but it is what it is.

Ron Washington speaks a dialect that probably has [African American Vernacular English](http://www.hawaii.edu/satocenter/langnet/definitions/aave.html) (AAVE) as its base, with some elements of the language of the neighborhood in New Orleans he lives in, with a few idiosyncratic uses thrown in. Unless you want to sound like Ron Washington you never have to use the sentence you ask about. The note about t-shirts indicates that such phrases sometimes resonate with a larger audience, and if you are interested in this phenomenon as related to Major League Baseball stars, you could read about the language of [Yogi Berra](http://ftw.usatoday.com/2015/09/the-50-greatest-yogi-berra-quotes) or [Dizzy Dean](http://www.encyclopediaofarkansas.net/encyclopedia/entry-detail.aspx?entryID=13):

> A new baseball language emerged from the Dean broadcasts. Runners “slud” into bases, players “throwed” the ball, a batter strode to the plate “confidentiality” and looked “mighty hitterish” in the batter’s box. If a batter “swang” at the pitch mightily, he “had quite a ripple” at the ball. If runners were on base and a foul ball was hit, the runners had to return to their “respectable” bases. Listeners could generally count on a Dean rendition of “The Wabash Cannonball” and a few baseball stories from Dean’s playing career.
>
> As Dean’s popularity as a broadcaster grew, some teachers expressed concern regarding Dean’s misuse of the language, but he withstood all challenges because of his great popularity with the fans. “I ain’t never met anybody that didn’t know what ain’t means” was Dean’s assessment.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite funny but no. There are no official writings in any English text that recognize "he do..." as a proper usage of grammar.

It has to be "He does...".

"I do/They do/We do" That's it.